# Android app extern database server

Tags: java, sqlite

When I want to create an SQLite external database for android application, do I have to have a server with database that is always running?

Comment: I doesn't have to run the whole time, just when you need to use your app.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, since it will be on a server. If the server isn't running, then your application won't be able to get any data from the database.

Answer (score 0):

There's a very important distinction that we're missing here - what it means to have a remote database.

SQLite is a flat-file [embedded database engine](https://www.sqlite.org/about.html).  You don't have a separate process running SQLite in the background like you would one for MySQL or PostgreSQL or Oracle, nor would you really *want* to - SQLite as a database is pretty limited in what it can do.

If you say that you're going to have a remote SQLite database, then that implies that you have some server somewhere that writes to and reads from this flat-file database.  If you can finagle that somehow, and make it secure, then more power to you - and yes, you could have this accessible remotely for your intents and purposes. Trust me though, you wouldn't *want* to.

What you're likely looking for is a way to remotely run [MySQL](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/connecting.html) or [PostgreSQL](http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/postgres-allow-remote-access-tcp-connection.html) instead, as these are proper database management systems (DBMS) which will be able to both service remote connections *and* give you a more expanded set of the SQL language.

Ultimately though, the database server must be running at all times.  You wouldn't be able to connect to the database if it's down, and you don't know the lifespan of the app (or when it's going to be accessed, etc).

Answer (score -1):

i got the below information from [SQLite home page](https://www.sqlite.org/)

SQLite is a software library that implements a self-contained, **serverless**, zero-configuration, transactional SQL database engine.

Based on the above statement you don't any server. I hope this information is useful to you.